# Best version of the WMD to use in a project?

Tags: wmd, wmd-editor

I'm interested in using the WMD editor in another project<sup>*</sup> but I'm not quite sure which version I should go with.

From trawling through the Stack overflow [blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/) I've found mention of a version on [google code](http://code.google.com/p/wmd/), plus [cky's version on github](http://github.com/cky/wmd/tree/master), as well as [derobin's](http://github.com/derobins/wmd/tree/master), which appears to be a more up to date version.

Then of course there are [a](http://github.com/olleolleolle/wmd/tree/master) [bunch](http://github.com/ChadBurggraf/wmd/tree/master) [of](http://github.com/adamsanderson/wmd/tree/master) [forks](http://github.com/thenduks/wmd/tree/master), which is leaving me a bit lost on where to begin.  I suspect the answer will be to use [derobin's version](http://github.com/derobins/wmd/tree/master) but thought I would check the collected wisdom before I dive in.

Thanks.

<sup>*</sup> Specifically, I want to try and integrate it with [Drupal](http://drupal.org/)'s [WYSIWYG module](http://drupal.org/project/wysiwyg), but I don't think that has significant bearing on the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, looks like [derobin's version](http://github.com/derobins/wmd/tree/master) is the winner.

Answer (score 1):

See episode 35 (30 December 2008) of the Stack Overflow podcast, which has some discussion on the WMD control. Minutes: 27-34.

https://stackoverflow.fogbugz.com/default.asp?W29022 for the transcript wiki